# How do I set up a nodejs server that gives the client the correct file by checking the url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to write a node js server that gives back whatever the user requested, if the resource is in the file system.

For example, if the request URL were `/index.html`, it would try to find a file called 'index.html' in the root directory and respond with a stream to that file. If the request were `/myscript.js`, it would do the same, finding a file called `myscript.js` and piping that to the response.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    if (request.method == "GET") {
        console.log(request.url);
        if (request.url == "/") { // if the url is "/", respond with the home page
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            fs.createReadStream("index.html").pipe(response);
        } else if (fs.existsSync("." + request.url)) {
            response.writeHead(200/*, {"Content-Type": request.headers['content-type']}*/);
            fs.createReadStream("." + request.url).pipe(response);
        } else {
            response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            response.end("404 Not Found");
        }
    } else {
        response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.end("404 Not Found");
    }
}).listen(port);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:' + port +'/');
```

There are a few things that I don't like about this code:

- Apparently `fs` thinks that whenever the path starts with `/`, the file does not exist, so I must add a `.` before the file path. See line 10 and 12. Will this always work? I feel like this is a really bad trick to work around the problem.
- I don't know the content type of the requested file (line 11). I searched online and found a lot of ways to do this with other modules that I have to install using npm. Is there something in node that will figure out the content type?

Comment: why don't you use `express`. It will do all that serving for you and you're code will be reduced too . https://expressjs.com/

Comment: Why don't you know the content type? You, as the server, *choose* the content type. If you serve html and js files, put the appropriate content types for them.

Comment: @Bergi so I need to check the extension and return an appropriate content type for that extension? I was hoping for a more "automatic" way...

Comment: You will need to make sure that you only serve files from a directory that you have chosen, and [nothing else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack).

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, checking the extension of the file is probably the simplest you can come up with. You could also look at the file content (some formats include magic numbers for this). However mime type detection is an imprecise science, and you should probably go with a whitelist.

Comment: @Bergi oh I see! What about the problem of `fs` thinking that `/index.html` doesn't exist but `./index.html` does? Do I just put a dot at the front?

Comment: @Sweeper Well `/index.html` is an absolute path, for a file located in the root of your file system. It *does* not exist. If you want to serve the files from the folder where the `node` process was started (which I wouldn't necessarily recommend), yes you put a `./` at the front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addressing your two bullet points:

- It makes sense that you would need a `.` when using `fs` because `fs` will look at the root directory of your system otherwise. Remember, the system root is different than your server root.
- One idea is to use `path.extname` and then a `switch` statement to set the content type like so.

The code below is taken from an [blog post](https://landofcode.io/node-js-server-tutorial-express-http-examples/#Serving_Static_Files_No_Framework) I wrote on how to set up a simple static server using Node without Express:

```
let filePath = `.${request.url}`; // ./path/to/file.ext
let ext = path.extname(filePath); // .ext
let contentType = 'application/octet-stream'; // default content type

if(ext === '') {

    filePath = './index.html'; // serve index.html
    ext = '.html';
}

switch (ext) {

    case '.html':
        contentType = 'text/html';
        break;

    case '.css':
        contentType = 'text/css';
        break;

    case 'js':
        contentType = 'text/javascript';
}
```

Comment: Also make the `default:` case throw an exception. If you only know these file types, you don't want to serve any others.

Comment: Added a comment to make it more clear that the default content type above is "application/octet-stream"